# How to find instance number of an object in java

Tags: java, object

Is there **some function** which takes object as an argument and return the instance number of the object?

By instance number I mean:

> The first instance of the class has instance number 1, the second has
>   2 and so on.

Comment: He want to say amount of instances of certain object

Comment: The first instance of the class has instance number 1, the second has 2 and so on.

Answer (score 3):

In this case you can initialize a private static counter and in object constructor increment it.